# How to check if object doesn't not exist in array than push to array?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading from Web API 'dates' and next to every date there is an hour(24) so I get 24h stamps and next to them I get 24 dates of the same day but I only need one date of each day. So that you could choose a date in option which date's weather you want to see.

```
function datos() {
    citySelected = document.getElementById("miestas").value;
    let xh = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xh.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xh.readyState === 4 && xh.status === 200) {
            let data = JSON.parse(xh.responseText);
            for(let i=0;i < data.forecastTimestamps.length; i++) {
                let dateV = [];
                if(data.forecastTimestamps[i].forecastTimeUtc.slice(0,10) === dateV){
                } else {
                    dateV.push(data.forecastTimestamps[i].forecastTimeUtc.slice(0,10));
                }
                let option = document.createElement("option");
                let datalist = document.getElementById("datuList");
                option.value = dateV[i];
                datalist.appendChild(option);
            }
        }
    }
    xh.open("GET", "https://api.meteo.lt/v1/places/"+citySelected+"/forecasts/long-term");
    xh.send();
}
```

So right now it pushes the first one, and other in options are "undefined".

Comment: if (!myArray.includes(thing)) {myArray.push(thing)}

Comment: You set `dateV` to an empty array in every iteration,  so you're always comparing to an empty array...

Comment: You cant compare Array's like that `someArray === dateV`.
This is always false. Even if they contain the same values.